# String to date conversion not working when language changed

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nslocale

Hi this is my code it is working fine when the device language is in English but when I change the change the language in french the date comes as nil.. Can anyone please help me to fix this problem.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:NSLocaleIdentifier]];
birthdayDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:birthdayStr]; //birthdayStr it contains Date string.
```

Comment: What is the string you are trying to convert to a date?

Comment: Thanks for your response Mon, 19 Apr 1993 00:00:00 -0400 this is my format

Comment: @Zaph: Can you please put some how to set like your suggestion?

Comment: So, this date you're trying to translate will always be in English, even if the device language is something else?

Comment: Hopefully the month will be in French when the device language is set to French. Otherwise set the local to English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, d LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
        [dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]; //This is the Stuff
```

I got my solution. Above code is working fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, d LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
let resultsDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```